# Does git INDEX contain the SHA-1 values of the versions of working tree and HEAD?

Tags: git, indexing, version-control

I have a technical doubt about the internals of the Git INDEX. I've read that the INDEX it's a binary data structure that keeps track of the versions (SHA-1) of each tracked/staged file in the three main areas: working tree, staging area and repository (HEAD).

However, I've used an INDEX visualization tool (https://github.com/sbp/gin) to inspect the file and I don't see those HEAD and working tree version SHA-1, neither I see anything about them in the docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/index-format)

I've got the idea about the 3 versions from this resources:

[Understanding Git — Index by Zvonimir Spajic](https://konrad126.medium.com/understanding-git-index-4821a0765cf)

[Introduction to Git - talk by Scott Chacon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbLVvrb2-fY)

It would look something like this

[Example - File modified after checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG0Tl.jpg)

I even asked chatGPT (which I don't like xD) just in case it confirmed this wasn't true, but chatGPT told me it's true!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're getting some terminology mixed up. The index _is_ the staging area. Those are two terms for the exact same thing. You won't find the `HEAD` there because it's a different, unrelated thing that's stored somewhere else (`.git/HEAD`).

Comment: _"the INDEX ... keeps track of the versions (SHA-1) of each tracked/staged file in the three main areas: working tree, staging area and repository (HEAD)."_ That statement seems to be confusing a few things. The index/staging area is essentially just a filesystem jammed into a single file. It's independent from the working tree and from the object database. The working tree is just an ordinary filesystem tree that typically contains the contents of HEAD's commit tree (or an actively modified version thereof). The notion of "versions (SHA-1)" is really only applicable to the object database.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I think I understand what the Stagin Area/Index/Cache and the Working Tree are. In fact, till I read the linked article and watch the linked video I assumed the `.git/INDEX` file was that "binary representation of a full tree, with references (SHA-1) to the blobs created/inserted in the object "DB" when you `git add` them. My question concerns only the `.git/INDEX` file and arised just when I read and watch those resources.